# SQL: Do columns in the Group By matter once a Unique Grouping is reached?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Because of the error, "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I'm wondering if, after so many groupings, the columns listed in Group By no longer affect the query. I have placed a simply query below for example.

```
Select FlockType, FarmNo, SettleDate, Sum(Weight) as Weight, Area, Size
FROM  Table
WHERE SettlementDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01  
GROUP BY FlockType, FarmNo, SettleDate, Area, Size
```

In this case above, because of the error mentioned, I am pretty much forced to  include "Area" and "Size" in my group by even though it doesn't contain any data that I would want to "Group" on. Grouping by the columns 'FlockType', 'FarmNo', and 'SettleDate' return a unique record. By those groupings there will never be two of the same records returned. Because of this, do the columns 'Area' and 'Size' affect the query? Say I had 100 columns that need to be selected, is it bad practice and/or would it affect the rest of my query if I include all of these other columns in my group by?

Comment: you could use an aggregation function like `MAX` or `MIN` over those columns and not include them in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: It isn't a bad practice, it's how it works and SQL Server tells you to do so unless you perform some aggregate operation on them

Comment: You do not type 100 columns by hands. Don't you? Just do a copy-paste. But I agree, it would be nice if SQL Server would group automatically by all columns not included in aggregation.

Comment: Just as a note, MySQL 5.x allows you to put non-grouped columns in the select, and randomly chooses one value among the resulting rows. I consider this a bug but MySQL considers it a "feature".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case above, because of the error mentioned, I am pretty much forced to include "Area" and "Size" in my group by even though it doesn't contain any data that I would want to "Group" on. Grouping by the columns 'FlockType', 'FarmNo', and 'SettleDate' return a unique record. By those groupings there will never be two of the same records returned.

SQLServer doesn't necessarily know this though, because at any time in the future, it COULD be the case that more than 1 row participates in the group. It won't look to the table definition and go "oh, flocktype/farmno/settledate is a unique key of the table, so there will never be more than row with that combination, so i'll let the user get away with just grouping on those columns, and adding in any other columns they like, without grouping/an aggregate function"

Why doesn't it do this? Probably because it's a needless complexity; as the user you can appreciate this, and it hence doesn't matter whether you do a `SELECT flock, farm, settledate, x GROUP BY flock, farm, settledate, x` or you do a `SELECT flock, farm, settledate, max(x) GROUP BY flock, farm, settledate` - the end result will be the same. By forcing you to specify to this extent, the query will carry on working even if the unique key is removed and more rows are added, but that's secondary to the notion that "unique keys are not considered in grouping situations, just to save you having to type a few characters, because they don't have to be and considering them could be awfully complex"

> Because of this, do the columns 'Area' and 'Size' affect the query?

No, whether you group them or aggregate them, there is only one of them so they make no difference either way. I don't think you'd find an appreciable performance difference either, as its essentially just "which side of a hash table do they sit on; as a single key or as a single value?"

> Say I had 100 columns that need to be selected, is it bad practice and/or would it affect the rest of my query if I include all of these other columns in my group by?

You have to group by a column or include it in an aggregate. You can group by more columns than you use (but it gets confusing because `select farm group by farm, flock, settle` generates loads of repeated records with the same farm in and nothing to tell them apart) but you cannot group by fewer columns than you use

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's more clear to me now. I was pretty sure it worked as you described but I wanted to make sure before I placed a few extra columns in the group by as described in a very large query where it was possible that lots of data could have been affected.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention was use of NULL, and whether any of your grouped columns is null. SQLServer treats NULL as a value in this regard and would eg only allow one row of farm=1,flock=1,settledate=null, but other database systems(and ansi sql itself) would allow multiple farm=1,flock=1,settle=null.. I donlt think it affects you, but just to appreciate how in some DB systems you could get different results for `MAX(x) GROUP BY farm,flock,settle` vs `x GROUP BY farm, flock,settle,x`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid grouping of some columns, but be able to use them in `SELECT` statement, then you should use aggregate functions under that columns. For example:

```
Select 
FlockType, FarmNo, SettleDate, 
Sum(Weight) as Weight, Max(Area) MaxArea, Max(Size) MaxSize
FROM  Table
WHERE SettlementDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01  
GROUP BY FlockType, FarmNo, SettleDate
```

The error means that that you've got SUM of `Weight` field and `GROUP` - one row, but SQL Server has also many OTHER rows with calculated column and it does not know what a row exactly should be chosen.

Comment: Do you know if one way is more efficient than the other performance wise? I assume that as long as what I'm calling a 'Unique Grouping' is met with the other columns in Group By that Max(column) would be the same as just selecting [column]

Comment: @user3841709 If you are doing just a `SELECT` without grouping it has the better performance than `SELECT ... GROUP BY` as SQL Server engine has not to do  extra operation such as `GROUPING`

Comment: @StepUp I think th way you've phrased that is misleading - you appear to be saying that `SELECT x, y GROUP BY x, y` is more onerous than `SELECT x, max(y) GROUP BY x` but given that the group of x has to be maintained and inspected in order to calc the max Y, then max(y) has a cost - you can't just write it off as "free" and say "you're not grouping on as many columns, so of course it's faster" - any MAX() operation involves some kind of grouping. If SQLServer does it as a hash table, thn the hashtable of X or X/Y has to be maintained, and Y is either a key or a value,but it has to be factored

Comment: @CaiusJard  no, I am saying that SELECT without GROUPING has better performance than SELECT with GROUPING.

Comment: That's not really relevant here though

Comment: @CaiusJard this question asked an OP